# Probability of getting into the same class

Tags: probability

A class has $60$ students. I want to divide this class into two groups at random each with $30$ students. John & Jane are two friends in this class. What is the probability that john and jane will be in the same class?

I get that $$|S| = {60\choose30}$$

How do I get the number of outcomes ?

Comment: If John and Jane are in the same class, then you just need to choose $28$ students more, out of the $58$ left out,and put them in that class ,to get a favourable outcome.Can you now see the answer?

Comment: 100% because "John & Jane are two friends in this class".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of elements in the sample space is the total number of ways $60$ students can be distributed into $2$ classes, which is
$$\binom{60}{30,30}$$

The number of elements in the set "John and Jane in the same class" is
$$\binom{58}{28,30}+\binom{58}{30,28}$$

To get the probability divide the two numbers 
$$\frac{2\cdot\dbinom{58}{28,30}}{\dbinom{60}{30,30}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{2\times58!}{28!\times30!}}{\dfrac{60!}{30!\times30!}}=\dfrac{2\times58!\times30!\times30!}{28!\times30!\times60!}=\dfrac{29}{59}$$

Answer (score 2):

John is in one class, so there are 29 remaining slots in his class and 30 slots in the other class.  Jane has a $29/(29+30) = 29/59$ chance of being in John's class.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, I think.